# Limit of recurrence relation $x_k= f(x_{k-1})$ for an increasing function $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, recurrence-relations

Is there a standard result out there that gives the following? It looks graphically like it must be true, but I'd like to appeal to a known result if possible.

Let $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$  be a continuous, strictly increasing function such that $f(1)=1$ and $f(x)>x$ for all $x\in[0,1)$. For any $x_0\in[0,1)$, inductively define $x_k\equiv f(x_{k-1})$. Then $\lim_{k\to\infty}x_k=1$.

Comment: Usually, you start by taking the limit of the recurrence relation itself, under the assumption that $\lim x_k$ exists. (call its value $L$)

Comment: I don't know if there is a name, but here is a short proof: $x_n$ is increasing and bounded above by 1, therefore converges, $\lim x_n =\lim f(x_n)$ so $L$ must be a fixed point of the function, which means $L=1$

Comment: @Lost1: The theorem that says the limit exists is named the monotonic convergence theorem or monotonic sequence convergence theorem, or something like that. The key phrase is 'monotonic sequence'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if there is a name, but here is a short proof: $x_n$ is increasing and bounded above by 1, therefore converges, $\lim x_n =\lim f(x_n)$ so $L$ must be a fixed point of the function, which means $L=1$ -- [Lost1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/853655/standard-results-for-limit-of-recurrence-relation#comment1760813_853655)

The theorem that says the limit exists is named the monotonic convergence theorem or monotonic sequence convergence theorem...  The key phrase is 'monotonic sequence'. -- [Hurkyl](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/853655/standard-results-for-limit-of-recurrence-relation#comment1760835_853655)